# working on FOREIGN LANGUAGE Windows PCs (Portable applications)

Tags: portable-apps, language

Looking for good tools for working on foreign language (including foreign charset) computers.

The main thing would be web browsing, but also working with the system, virus-checks etc.
Changing keyboard settings somehow is essential, and perhaps some kind of on-screen keyboard)

Think this would be portable applications on a stick, but it could also be something installed, or remote.

(I guess this would be a bit the same as the best "Portable Application" suite for support, but there are  special needs for foreign charset computers like manipulating keyboard settings, onscreen keyboard etc )

Comment: What do you mean? I work all day on a foreign language Windows PC and need no applications for that?! It's built-in.

Comment: Often I have to do stuff on Chinese PC's (And i don't know any Chinese)

Answer (score 0):

In the regional settings you can add any keyboard layout you want. Then you get the language switcher in the taskbar. Switch it to the language you want. Then you can press WIN+R and enter in the "Run"-Command-Box `osk.exe` or just `osk`. Then you get the on-screen-keyboard with your selected keyboard layout.

This is a built-in function. If you need something else, please specify.

Switching the language does not change the menu items and dialog texts of the (Windows!) Operating System. For that case you need portable apps in your language. A very huge selection of such tools can be found at [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/).